# Calculate the SUM of the difference and multiplication of some columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have the following formula to calculate a KPI :

```
SUM((PFIINVESTISSEMENT - 
(ENVMTINITIAL-VSTD_ENVMTDISPO))*DPPMTPART)
```

When I try to apply it in DAX :

```
KPI1 :=SUM(
DPPMTPART *
([PROP_MtDemandeFin] -(PFIINVESTISSEMENT - 
    (ENVMTINITIAL-VSTD_ENVMTDISPO) )
)
```

I get the following error :

> The SUM function only accepts a column reference as an argument.

Comment: Can you provide information on your tables.  How are they joined.  Are the values in your formula all columns or are some measures and some columns.  Are they in the same table?  Those will all be important to know to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: @Spevy they are all in the same table.

Comment: What is the schema of these columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [SUMX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax) iterator function. Using it, your measure should look like this (where `Table` is the name of your table):

```
KPI1 = SUMX('Table', [DPPMTPART] *
   ([PROP_MtDemandeFin] -([PFIINVESTISSEMENT] - ([ENVMTINITIAL]-[VSTD_ENVMTDISPO]))))
```